# SilverStripe 3.3 - Add CMS Fields as JavaScript variables

Tags: javascript, silverstripe

I'm trying something different for a SilverStripe project: I need to find a way to take fields in the CMS and put them into JavaScript variables for use in a JavaScript file.

For starters, I have a Header CMS field in `Page.php`:

```
private static $db = array(
    'Header' => 'HTMLText'
);

public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new HTMLEditorField('Header', 'Header'));

    return $fields;
}
```

And I want to reference that field inside a JavaScript file as a variable:

```
       {
            id: 'Text-Intro',
            type: 'text',
            rect: ['251px', '250px','641px','71px','auto', 'auto'],
            text: [Header variable needs to go here],
            align: "left",
            font: ['Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif', 25, "rgba(0,0,0,1.00)", "500", "none", "normal"]
        },
```

I tried making use of the Requirements::javascriptTemplate() function but the variable isn't recognized inside the `detail-page_edge.js` file:

```
public function init() {
    parent::init();

    Requirements::javascriptTemplate('/themes/simple/javascript/detail-page_edge.js', array(
        'Header' => $this->Header
    ));
}
```

Something must be missing, or maybe this is just outdated? I've never tried this in SilverStripe before. I don't have much of a choice, though, considering how this project is setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use SilverStripe template syntax for simple variable-replacement. So your JS file should read:

```
// ... plain JS code
text: '$Header',
// ... more JS code
```

Please note, that you can't use more complex template syntax, such as `<% loop … %>` or `<% if … %>`, as `javascriptTemplate` will just do variable substitution.

If you need the full template features, you could render a `.ss` template file to string and output it with `Requirements::customScript`. I don't think you should ever do that though… even processing JS files through `javascriptTemplate` seems off. I'd rather use HTML data-attributes in your regular markup (eg. `.ss` templates) and write the JavaScript in a way that it'll grab the required attributes and builds upon the markup.

Also: Make sure your path to the file is correct. Instead of writing the absolute path:

```
'/themes/simple/javascript/detail-page_edge.js'
```

I suggest you use the following:

```
$this->ThemeDir() . '/javascript/detail-page_edge.js'
```